# Eclipse not starting tomcat-7 server in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am trying to debug my code, the eclipse doesn't stating in debug mode, however it is working fine in normal start.

Below is the exception I got in eclipse popup :

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 90
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

When I look in to the console everything looks fine, please have a look....

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security/oauth/details.xml]
Mar 11, 2015 11:48:38 AM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [dev/com.myPack.plat.data.mongo.config.props/mongo-config.properties]
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I think that this is an issue with the Eclipse/Tomcat integration. Try rebuilding the project or deleting and creating a new run configuration.

Comment: I agree with Simon that it's an Eclipse/Tomcat integration, a question @Shamim, does the server run, do you get the `INFO: Server startup in [milis] ms` in the server output? or once the message shows, the server instance is terminated?

Comment: did u try increasing the time from 90 sec ?

Comment: @sayan Yes I tried to increase the time up to 120 sec but the problem remain the same,

Comment: @tbc No, the server does not run when I try to start in debug mode, Anyway I rebuilt the project in my workspace, now its working fine. But, it is not the solution question remains in my mind why that exception occurred.

Comment: @Shamim most likely, something got stuck in your project due to file lock or something of the sort, so the server couldn't undeploy/deploy in timely fashion .. you MIGHT find something if you dig in the logs ..

Comment: @tbc Thankyou, I will dig in for sure, when I get a chance.

Comment: This also sometimes happens if you have a breakpoint in some code that's called on the application startup - the breakpoint triggers then after some time the timeout kicks in and kills the server process. So make sure it's not the case. I've hit that in the past and ended up increasing the timeout to 9999.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the solution, your main problem is that you have included breakpoint in your program. If you don't remember your breakpoint, you can skip those breakpoints during execution of your program. Follow these steps.

Only applicable for Eclipse.

Menu---> Run---> Skip all Breakpoints

Now you can start your tomcat server easily.

Happy learning, happy coding
http://www.oliverspost.com/ for more information

Answer (score 12):

Removing all breakpoints fixed my case

Comment: [Uwe Lindenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6625723/uwe-lindenberg) would like to add: “Removing all breakpoints fixed my problem also”.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reason for not starting tomcat in debug mode in eclipse. Below checkpoint could help you to resolve the issue.

1. If you are using Window operation system then first check your window firewall specially inbound rule. If it contains javaTM in list then enable rule if it is disable and select enable connection and click on apply and ok.
2. Check your eclipse preference jre and tomcat runtime configuration. JDK path is more preferable.
3. Increase timeout if require
4. Before you start the server, check process in task manager or for mac user check activity monitor. java process need to be kill if it is running.
5. Restart eclipse and clean build and debug. If issue still persist then take new instance of eclipse. some time eclipse internal setting also restrict tomcat debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is one other possible solution, Just check out the breakpoints whether they are on line or parameters. i think to remove all those break points is best way to start server in debug mode.

normally this happens when we do pull frequently from git.

Answer (score 1):

Removing breakpoints also worked for me, in fact my problems started when I set a breakpoint in this sentence:

```
private void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException
```

I don't know if the type of the parameters matter, but it was the first time this happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the tomcat couple times fixed it for me.[image]